# Exclude class methods from jacoco analysis

Tags: junit, jacoco

I am looking for a way to exclude specific class methods in my jacoco analysis. I am aware of the "excludes" property but that only applies to entire classes.

In my case i have generated methods that distort the coverage report so i would like to exclude them from the report.

Comment: I think it's on a TODO list, see here: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/FilteringOptions

Answer (score 1):

**JaCoCo supports now** (in 2018, I know the question is from 2012) since **[version 0.8.0](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/tree/v0.8.0)** *(released on 2018/01/02)*  **ignoring methods** with annotion `@lombok.Generated`.

So this can be used as a workaround also for other generated methods (if you are able to tag them this way) or even for "hand-written" methods if you really want (although this was probably not the intention of the authors).

Answer (score -1):

You can actually use wildcards in the excludes property, that is if you're using ant to run the jacoco unit test:

> Blockquote
>   excludes - A list of class names that should be excluded from execution analysis. The list entries are separated by a colon (:) and may use wildcard characters (* and ?). Except for performance optimization or technical corner cases this option is normally not required.
>   http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html

You can also exclude files from the report generation process using simple ant [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) tasks:

```
<jacoco:report>    
    <executiondata>
        <file file="jacoco.exec"/>
    </executiondata>

    <structure name="Example Project">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="classes"/>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
            <fileset dir="src"/>
        </sourcefiles>
    </structure>

    <html destdir="report"/>

</jacoco:report>
```

You may have to experiment with the two to get the desired results.