# How can I exclude certain methods from Jacoco's analysis in Maven configuration?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I read (some of) Jacoco's documentation and googled, but haven't found an answer to this question

How do I exclude certain methods from Jacoco's reports **in Maven configuration**?

*(please note the emphasis and don't suggest [putting `@Generated`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711080/23539854) on my hand-written methods which is semantically nonsensical and an ugly kludge, in my opinion)*

It's straightforward to exclude certain directories or classes

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <!-- executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Exception.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/MyApplication.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
```

but it seems a bit more tricky with methods. One thing's for sure, this doesn't work

```xml
                        <exclude>**/*.equals</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.get*</exclude>
```

*Is* there a way to statically exclude certain method patterns from coverage reports to begin with?

Comment: If the answer is "You can't do it", I'll take it too

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is "You can't do it". However, you can be clever about the way you name the annotation like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824761/how-would-i-add-an-annotation-to-exclude-a-method-from-a-jacoco-code-coverage-re . The only criteria for the annotation seems to be that it should contain "Generated" in the name. You could tweak the name to fit your case.